# How can I conditionally print a startup message in JShell, depending on the current feedback mode?

Tags: jshell

There seems to be a lot of options for configuring JShell feedback mode and prompt, as well as the ability to pre-define presets, and to save them between sessions. However, what I want is to print an "initializing" message using a `--startup` script, but only when using normal feedback mode.

When using normal mode, I want the message to be displayed:

```bash
$ echo 'println(myApp.whoami())' | jshell --startup PRINTING --startup init.jsh -
Initializing JShell for MyApplication...
Ready.

root
```

But when using concise mode, like when you start JShell with the `-q` option, I want the initialize message to be suppressed:

```bash
$ echo 'println(myApp.whoami())' | jshell --startup PRINTING --startup init.jsh -q -
root
```

I spent quite a bit of time looking at the options for `/set`, but could not find anything that worked. I tried searching for a way to detect the current mode to use it in an `if` statement in the initialization script, but I can only find a way to set it, not to get it. I also tried finding a system property that had information about the mode, but there wasn't any. I also tried with, and without, the `--startup PRINTING` option (using `System.{out|err}` for the messages instead).